# Javascript: FBXLoader not displaying anything

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, fbx

I am trying to use FBXLoader to display an FBX Binary file that I get from an API. When I check the console log, it shows that it downloads 100%, but then nothing shows up. I've tried this with and without the mesh part. The only thing I can think of is that the API I'm calling to sends this FBX file back with Content-Type being application/download. I'm not sure if this matters because I still receive the FBX Binary file and can view the whole file when I view Response in Chrome Dev Tools.

```
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 1, 2000);
        // camera.position.set( 600, 1150, 5 );
        // camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );
        // camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( -100, 0, 0 ) );

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // model
        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
          console.log(item, loaded, total);
        };
        var onProgress = function(xhr) {
          if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
            console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
          }
        };
        var onError = function(xhr) {};
        var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(manager);
        loader.load(xhr.responseURL, function(geometry) {
          mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
          mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
          mesh.position.y = 150;
          mesh.position.x = 0;
          scene.add(mesh);
          console.log(mesh);
        }, onProgress, onError);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(500, 500);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        var container = document.getElementById("ava");
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

[screenshot of 100% FBX download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOaHN.png)

Comment: You are not adding the camera to the scene, You don't seem to be calling `renderer.render(scene, camera);` anywhere.

Comment: @2pha I added that and I still get the same thing :/

Comment: Where did you add it? You will have to make sure the scene is rendered at least once after the model has loaded.

Comment: @2pha I added it in. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would have the `renderer.render(scene, camera)` call in a loop, but not always.

In your case, you don't seem to have a render loop, so you are at least going to need a call to renderer.render(scene, camera) in your loader onload callback.

```
// set up your renderer first.
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(500, 500);
var container = document.getElementById("ava");
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader(manager);
loader.load(xhr.responseURL, function(geometry) {
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
  mesh.scale.set( 10, 10, 10 );
  mesh.position.y = 150;
  mesh.position.x = 0;
  scene.add(mesh);
  console.log(mesh);
  // Call render here as a mesh has been added.
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}, onProgress, onError);
```